# How to find parse rows and enter data into a table

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a task in Excel 2007. I just started this job and I have to write a macro with a couple of steps and I'm kind of at a loss. Could someone help me along, and if I need to provide more information please let me know.

1. The macro has to loop through a single column top to bottom one cell at a time.
2. When the macro gets to the value it searches for that particular value throughout the entire workbook of the cell.
3. The macro looks at the next column of the value that is was searching for and references that value in another column of a separate worksheet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Sel_Class()

    Dim cell As Range, rFind2 As Range, tagID As Integer, alias As String, sh As Workbooks

    For Each cell In Worksheets("CList").Range("B2:B167").cells

        Set cell = .find(what:="ActiveCell.Value", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=x1ByRows, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            for all sheets in workbook
            .find(what:="ActiveCell.Value", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=x1ByRows, SearchFormat:=False)

            Do
                List.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = rFind1.Offset(2)
                Set rFind2 = .find(what:="Recruiter", After:=rFind1)
                If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then
                    Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = rFind2.Offset(2)
                End If
                Set rFind1 = .find(what:="FG ID", After:=rFind2)
            Loop While rFind1.Address <> sAddr
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you expand on the problem a bit, that was quite confusing, also let us know where your code is failing at the moment.

Comment: I have 2 accounts (don't know how but I do) sorry for the late response. I'm having trouble with the loops to find a cell value throughout a workbook then copy and pasting the value of the cell found into a fixed column. Hope that makes better sense.